# Can't run UBUNTU 16.10 neither from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 16.10

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 (in dual boot with Windows 10) on my Asus laptop a couple of months ago. Everything was fine for the first two weeks, than I could no longer selected Ubuntu at boot and Windows started by default. If I try to run a Live version of Ubuntu I get this error message:

[image]

I tried Boot-Repair but it didn't work. I even formatted the whole hard disk, reinstalled Windows 10 but the problem persists.
Is there someone that can help me?

My Notebook is an **Asus K501UB**.

Comment: * I even formatted the whole hard disk, but the problem persist* So, you formatted the whole drive then what? Reinstalled Windows 10 and Ubuntu? Also for such questions please always include hardware specs. UEFI dual-boot can be tricky in some notebooks, requiring additional specs. And what are you running for the live session, a DVDm a USB? Hoe did you burned it?

Comment: I reinstalled Windows 10 (i can't reinstall Ubuntu, that's actually my problem). My Notebook is an Asus K501UB, wich specs do you need? I'm trying to run Ubuntu form USB (i don't have a DVD reader), burned with UNetbootin.

Comment: The edits I've made to improve your question should have been done by you. That said, when making an USB from Windows use Rufus, the recommended tools and select the option depending on the mode Windows was installed because you need to boot and install Ubuntu the same way. Make sure the ISO has been correctly downloaded. Finally, you may need the ǹomodeset`boot parameter because Asus K501UB has a Nvidia Graphics card (it should work acceptably with the default open-source drivers, booting a properly done USB flash drive will tell.

Comment: The mystery still is how you managed to install it before? What changed?

Comment: Right, that was what i asked myself too, I really can't understand that. Anyway i'll try with Rufus and I let you know if it works (I've alredy tryied to donwload the ISO many times). Thank you!

Comment: It actually worked! I really, really, really thank you!

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question detailing the steps. I'll try to improve it later, if needed. Also don't forget to accept the answer, after a day or so.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just by burning the Ubuntu's ISO file with Rufus (instead of UNetbootin, wich I used before). Everything works well now.

Comment: No need for `nomodeset` then?

Comment: Nope, everything goes